# OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, array

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lista chamar = new Lista();
        String[] vetor = {"Palavra", "Letra"};
        chamar.adicionar(vetor);
    }
}
class Lista {
    ArrayList<String> lista;
    public Lista() {
        lista = new ArrayList<>();
    } public void adicionar(String[] vetor) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < vetor.length) {
            lista.add(vetor[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Quando executo, aparece o erro "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space", gostaria de saber como consertá-lo.

Comment: Este erro independe do seu código: depende de como o Java é executado. Como você está executando este código?

Comment: Debugando pelo NetBeans.

Comment: esse código compila?? seu construtor está errado.. não creio que seja esse o código que você está rodando

Comment: Sim, compila, @Math.

Comment: @Patrick cara, abri o IDE e aqui não compila, falta o `()` no seu construtor

Comment: Ah sim, esqueci desse detalhe.

Comment: Ok, corrigi aqui e rodei, e não estourou a memória. Nao tem mais nada divergente do que você postou e do que você está rodando?

Comment: Não, pode ser o computador, pois não é sempre que acontece esse erro? Estou usando um Windows 8 64bits em um pc com 1GB de memória RAM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como não há nenhum erro no código talvez o problema esteja no tamanho do *heap space* do Java.

Como a sua máquina tem apenas 1 GB de memória RAM o tamanho padrão do *heap* do Java pode estar muito pequeno.

Tente aumentar o tamanho do heap nas opções do projeto no NetBeans:

1. Clique com o botão direito no seu projeto e escolha "**Propriedades**"
2. Selecione a categoria "**Executar**"
3. Digite **-Xmx128m** no campo "**Opções da VM**"

-Xmx128m diz pra VM executar com 128 MB de *heap space*, você pode alterar esse valor pra mais (-Xmx256m) ou menos (-Xmx64m) conforme a necessidade.

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se você tem permissões de escrita no diretório/drive onde está instalado o Netbeans. Esse OutOfMemoryError pode acontecer em instalações onde o usuário que executa o Netbeans não possui muitas permissões na máquina.