# Como alterar o heap space da VM em um projeto da Plataforma do Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

estou tendo o seguinte problema:

Tenho um projeto da *Aplicação da Plataforma Netbeans* que durante a execução a aplicação trava de vez e nada mais responde (um minuto de execução é o suficiente pra travar, isso possivelmente ocorre devido a grandes consultas que  a aplicação necessita fazer). E esse problema ocorre em uma proporção de 2 vezes a cada 10 execuções.

Quando o problema ocorre a saída do NetBeans não captura nenhum erro, no entanto, na versão instalada do projeto consegui capturar o seguinte erro: OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Pois bem, vi [nesse tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12794/26814) a sugestão para mudar as opções da VM. Contudo como o projeto é uma *Aplicação da Plataforma Netbeans*, não encontrei em propriedades as opções da VM.

Em um outro tópico da versão inglês do site, vi a sugestão de adicionar a propriedade `run.args.extra=-J-Xmx1024m` trecho no arquivo **project.properties**, mas aparentemente essa propriedade parece ser ignorada e o problema continua ocorrer.

Alguém sabe como posso alterar as configurações da VM em uma *Aplicação da Plataforma Netbeans*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minha sugestão é modificar diretamente no arquivo de configuração do netbeans:

**netbeans.conf**

Você ponde encontra-lo em:

> instalação global:
> *${nb-install}/etc/netbeans.conf*
>
> ou
>
> usuário local: *${userdir}/etc/netbeans.conf*

Procure pelo item: **netbeans_default_options**

```
# Options used by NetBeans launcher by default:
# (can be overridden by explicit command line switches)
#
# Note that default -Xmx and -XX:MaxPermSize are selected for you automatically.
# You can find these values in var/log/messages.log file in your userdir.
# The automatically selected value can be overridden by specifying -J-Xmx or
# -J-XX:MaxPermSize= here or on the command line.
#
# If you specify the heap size explicitly, you may also want to enable
# Concurrent Mark & Sweep garbage collector.
# (see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqGCPauses)
#

 
netbeans_default_options="-J-Xms1536m -J-Xmx2048m  ... outras opções ..."
```

No exemplo adicionei:

- heap inicial = Xms
- heap maximo=   Xmx

Comment: Cara, valeu pela resposta, mas infelizmente não resolveu meu problema. Alterei as configurações do netbeans no **netbeans.conf** da pasta de intalação, mas ao executar o jar sempre gera com -J-Xms32m  -J-Xm64m.
Mas sua resposta foi de muita serventia, pois pude refinar minha pesquisa pela resposta. Pelo que entendi pela [FAQ do Netbeans] (http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqStartupParameters) isso aplica-se até a versão 7.x. Utilizo o Netbeans 8.0.2. Pesquisarei para tal versão

Comment: @Dener você tentou checar o messages.log pra ver se alguma informação util é retornada. Vou fazer uns testes aqui e te retorno com uma segunda opinião.

Comment: vi aqui o message.log, e infezlimente lá não está mostrando nada fora do normal